# Passing info message to a Wicket page while using PageParameters

Tags: java, wicket, friendly-url

Does Wicket somehow allow passing both of the following kinds of params in a PageParameters object? Apparently not?

- `accountId` which **is** shown in the URL (`/account/<ID>`)
- `infoMessage` parameter which is **not** shown in the (bookmarkable) URL

I'm currently using IndexedHybridUrlCodingStrategy for the page in question, and simply trying parameters "0" and "infoMessage" gives this exception:

> WicketMessage: Not all parameters were encoded. Make sure all
>   parameter names are integers in consecutive order starting with zero.
>   Current parameter names are: [0, infoMessage]

If I change "infoMessage" parameter name into "1", it works, but yields an ugly URL (in this case something like `/account/42/Tosite%20108207%20tallennettiin.5`) which is not what I want.

---

Now, the obvious answer perhaps is that **infoMessage shouldn't be in PageParameters**. But thing is, I tried adding it as normal constructor parameter instead, like so:

```
public AccountPage(PageParameters parameters, String infoMessage) {
    // ...
}
```

But this approach fails in one important use case. After deleting a persistent "Record" object related to the Account, the following does **not** load the AccountPage properly (the deleted record is still visible). This code is executed in onClick() of an AjaxFallbackLink.

```
setResponsePage(new AccountPage(AccountPage.pageParameters(account), message));
```

On the other hand, my original approach...

```
setResponsePage(AccountPage.class, AccountPage.pageParameters(account));
```

... works fine, as it somehow loads the AccountPage "more thoroughly", but, again, I don't know how to pass the infoMessage parameter cleanly.

(`AccountPage.pageParameters()` above is a simple static utility for creating appropriate PageParameters with "0" = account id. The AccountPage constructor always loads the account from persistence using the ID.)

Any ideas? Perhaps using AjaxFallbackLink partially causes the problem?

Using Wicket 1.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I see in your question, you try to render both a bookmarkable page and show a feedback message to the user (most probably in a `FeedbackPanel`), but you don't want that message to be part of the URL.

What you want to do is tell the `Session` that you have an informational message, and let the feedback panel handle the message.

```
@Override void onSubmit() {
    ... save object ...
    getSession().info("Object ... has been saved");
    setResponsePage(ObjectPage.class, new PageParameters("id="+object.getId()));
}
```

In this case you tell Wicket to temporarily store a message in the session, until it gets rendered by a feedback panel. This idiom is also known as "flash messages".

You can't use both `PageParameters` and another parameter as constructor arguments, because Wicket can't create your page instance with such a constructor when the page is requested. Wicket only knows how to instantiate pages with default constructors or pages with a `PageParameters` parameter.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I was trying to do; thanks! Nice that the message stored with `getSession().info()` gets automatically picked up by the target page's feedback panel.