# wicket url parameters with stateful pages

Tags: java, url, wicket

on an application i develop i'm trying to keep a nice and readable url for the application's pages.
i start with url as follows:
http://somedomain.com/context/?param1=value&param2=value
where context is the application mount path and param1 and param2 are some parameters passed to the application.
the problem is that when i move to another page the url changes to be as follows:
https://somedomain.com/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:something&Title=something&group=something
the way i'm moving between pages is as follows:

> getRequestCycle().setResponsePage(new otherPage(obj1, obj2,
>   pageParameters)

where obj1 and obj2 are objects required for the initialization of the page.
as i understood from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390953/how-can-i-create-a-wicket-url-that-hides-its-parameters) post using

> `RequestCycle().setResponsePage(Page page)`

creates a stateful page which is not bookmarkable and does not display the parameters, while using

> `RequestCycle().setResponsePage(Class<C> pageClass, PageParameters
>   pageParameters)`

creates a stateless page which displays the parameters.
the problem is that i use the first one, as i must create the page myself so i could pass the two objects to it.
is there any way to keep the url in its original bookmarkable format and remove wicket's parameters from it?
i tried almost every suggestion posted on this site and others but none of them fits my case, as they suggest to let wicket create the page itself (with the second option of setResponsePage).
any help will be much appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Have you tried mounting your pages to specific URLs? That `.../?param1=...` construct isn't looking very nice.

Comment: the problem is that the url is not fixed - the parameters values and even the parameters themselves may change from one request to another. this is not a problem as the url is being generated for the users, i just want to keep the initial url fixed (or almost fixed, just not the unreadable wicket url)

Comment: The parameter values might change, that's fine. But you can still [mount bookmarkable pages](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/pages.html) and that should solve this problem.

Comment: the post in the link you added exactly describes my problem, but does not solve it. in fact, according to this post, it seems that what i'm intending to do is not supported by wicket (in "Not-bookmarkable pages" section). it says that if the page is stateful and doesn't have a constructor that wicket can use to create it, then the page must created explicitly in the code, and can be reached only by redirection. my problem is not with reaching the page, but only with keeping the url nice and readable.

Comment: also, what you suggest (mounting to specific url) is impossible for my case, because as i wrote, the parameters themselves may change - there is a set of parameters (tens of) that may or may not be passed.

Comment: IT would help if you posted some of your page code then. I still don't understand what your problem is: mounting pages is a perfectly straightforward operation and is completely independent of the number and variability of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

from your url example i see you are using Wicket 1.4. I believe 1.5 will do what you want out of the box. in Wicket 1.4 you can achieve a similar result by mounting the page using HybridUrlCodingStrategy.

Comment: and if that one doesnt do exactly what you want you can try writing your own, although in Wicket 1.4 it is not easy. Lots of improvements were made in this area in 1.5

Comment: i tried the HybridUrlCodingStrategy as well as the MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy and also wrote my own strategy, none of them worked. what i did notice is that when redirecting to a page with getRequestCycle().setResponsePage(new otherPage(obj1, obj2, pageParameters) wicket doesn't use the chosen url coding strategy at all. why is this, and how can i make it use the preferred strategy?